# How do I apply state transition inside AngularJS $rootScope event listeners?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-http-auth

I am currently facing a problem in using [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) library which is handling a state transition from events of **event:auth-loginRequired**. I am using [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for my routing systems.

Anyway here's some pieces of code from the library that emit the events :

```
case 401:
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    httpBuffer.append(config, deferred);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired', rejection);
    return deferred.promise;
```

And I was catching the events with these pieces of codes inside **myApp.run**

```
$rootScope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function(){
    console.log('Token Invalid / Expired');
    $state.transitionTo('login');
});
```

I was able to get the **'Token Invalid / Expired'** inside my console. However, the state transition didn't work at all and I didn't get any errors on my console too. I've tried using **$location.path('/login')**, but it doesn't work too.

Can anyone please help me with the solutions? Any kind of help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try using `$state.go` instead of `$state.transitionTo`. I believe it's the same but it sets some parameters by default. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tried that too, but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE - SOLVED]

Sorry, I think I've **found the solution**, **it's not because of the transition doesn't works inside Angular events**, but I was so stupid that I myself have an event.preventDefault() handling whenever the app tried to redirect to login state (which I was trying to redirect when the app catches the events) if there's still a token inside the browser's cookies. I'm so sorry for the question.

Once again thank you for trying to help me!